# How to change the n-th item of a list in NetLogo?

Tags: list, netlogo

I am new to NetLogo, and I am trying to write a code to list one of the turtles' parameters for all turtles and in each step change that list. But since some items of the list should be modified and I work with their position in the list, I was wondering someone could help how I can write a code to change the n-th item of that list (I think that replace-item does not work).

Thanks

Comment: `replace-item` does in fact replace the nth item of a list. So in order to help you, we need to see exactly how you tried to use `replace-item`, and you need to tell us why you concluded that it "does not work".

Comment: I have named my list (mylist) and I want the n-th item (which I defined n as another parameter, named: n) to be changed to: n-th item * (1 + another-parameter). So I have written this part like how I wrote in the next comment:

Comment: replace-item n mylist (? * (1 + another-parameter))

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more of the code than just that? We need to see more of the code to know if you're using `?` correctly. Also, what "didn't work" about it? Did you get an error message? If so, what was it? Did you get incorrect behavior? If so, what was it?

Comment: The problem was that before using replace-item, I didn't use a variable name to assign the result of replace-item function. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace-item` command creates a new list:

```
to test
  let lst01 [0 1 2 3]
  let lst02 replace-item 0 lst01 99
  print (word "the first list is unchanged: " lst01)
  print (word "the new list is: " lst02)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I just realized I should have named the replace-item function. It worked.